# Google App Engine, GWT in development mode and Maven 2

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, maven-2, intellij-idea

Currently I'm developing project with GAE/GWT. I'm using  IntelliJ IDEA CE so there's no simple way of doing GWT development (it doesn't contain GWT plugin). However it seems to be possible to run the GWT server in development mode, so it will be able to pick up the changes made to classes.

There is some solitions to make IDEA CE GWT-friendly, like http://java.dzone.com/tips/gwt-development-intellij-idea. However nothing about GAE+GWT.

So now I'm looking for the way of starting GAE application (mvn gae:run) with having GWT in development mode. Can you please advice?

Answer (score 3):

So what did I do in order to get it working:

1) add output directory settings so maven will generate files in place where GWT will expect them:

```
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
```

2) configure maven-gwt-plugin to respect your GAE app home

```
 <extraJvmArgs>-Dappengine.sdk.root=${appengine.sdk.root}</extraJvmArgs>
```

3) configure maven-gae-plugin to provide correct paths for GAE home

```
 <configuration>
    <sdkDir>${appengine.sdk.root}</sdkDir>
    <jvmFlags>-Dappengine.sdk.root=${appengine.sdk.root}</jvmFlags>
 </configuration>
```

4) set the property to point to the home of GAE installation:

```
<appengine.sdk.root>/path/to/gae/home</appengine.sdk.root>
```

and then you will be able to run the server

```
mvn gwt:run
```

as well as debug it

```
mvn gwt:debug
```

works fine with IntelliJ IDEA CE 10, but don't forget to run

mvn war:exploded

after every "mvn clean" task

Answer (score 3):

Just add following lines to gwt-maven-plugin configuration:

```
<server>com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher</server>
<appEngineVersion>${gae.version}</appEngineVersion>
<extraJvmArgs>-Dappengine.sdk.root=${project.build.directory}/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}</extraJvmArgs>
```

Then run your application as usually - `mvn gwt:run`

Answer (score 1):

In our project we use this steps - first run maven task - 
`mvn gae:debug` and the second is remote connection on specific port(5005) to specific address. 
If you required more explanation please welcome.

Comment: This wouldn't help in debugging client and server-side code of GWT, because it doesn't start GWT in development mode :(